# Why do I have a memory leak in UITableView while interacting and scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

my tableview is working fine and loading all the data without issues. I run into problems when I use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and add/remove the checkbox on the cell. I'll check a cell in the first 10, scroll down and see a checkbox on a cell I didn't tap.

What is causing this issue? Below is my tableview code.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"reuseCellForFilter";
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
Category *category = [self.categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = category.title;

return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return self.categories.count;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{


NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
Category *category = [self.categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [self.titles addObject:category];
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    for (Category *categoryID in [self.titles reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
        if (categoryID.categoryID == category.categoryID) {
            [self.titles removeObject:categoryID];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: are you sure if (categoryID.categoryID == category.categoryID) works correct for variables of pointer type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save checked/unchecked state in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and then restore it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

For example:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"reuseCellForFilter";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectionStyle = [self.selected containsObject:category.categoryID] ? UITableViewCellSelectionStyleCheckmark : UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    Category *category = [self.categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = category.title;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
    Category *category = [self.categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([self.selected containsObject:category.categoryID]) {
        [self.selected removeObject:category.categoryID];
        self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
}
```

You also have a problem in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. Marking category as checked you add this category to an array. To uncheck category you remove `categoryID` from array.

```
[self.titles addObject:category];
...
[self.titles removeObject:categoryID];
```